# how can i change the TextStyle of showDateRangePicker() or showDateRangePicker() in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-text, flutter-theme, flutter-dialog

> Want to change the TextStyle of `helpText` in `showDateRangePicker()` in Flutter.

### Can anybody Help.

[image: This the UI right now.]

[image: Want to Increase the size of this & color too]

---

```
  buildMaterialDatePicker({BuildContext context, SearchVM model}) 
   async {
    final DateTimeRange picked = await showDateRangePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: initialDate,
      helpText: 'Select a Date or Date-Range',
      fieldStartHintText: 'Start Booking date',
      fieldEndHintText: 'End Booking date',
      currentDate: initialDate,
      lastDate: DateTime(2020, initialDate.month + 1, 
      initialDate.day),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
              primary: Colors.greenAccent,
              onPrimary: oppColor,
              surface: Colors.greenAccent,
              onSurface: oppColor,
            ),
            dialogBackgroundColor: mainColor,
          ),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, according to the answer of  `abbas jafary` answer.
I deep Dived into the Documentation of the `showDateRangePicker()` (you can do so using `Ctrl+ Right-Clicking`) and found what `texstTheme` it is using for that `Text`.

```
 Text(
       helpText,
       style: textTheme.overline.apply(
       color: headerForeground,),
 ),
```

So, Then I wrapped my Widget with `Theme` and updated the `textTheme` field.

```
buildMaterialDatePicker({BuildContext context, SearchVM model}) async {
    final DateTimeRange picked = await showDateRangePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: initialDate,
      helpText: 'Select a Date or Date-Range',
      fieldStartHintText: 'Start Booking date',
      fieldEndHintText: 'End Booking date',
      currentDate: initialDate,
      lastDate: DateTime(2020, initialDate.month + 1, initialDate.day),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
              primary: Colors.greenAccent,
              onPrimary: oppColor,
              surface: Colors.greenAccent,
              onSurface: oppColor,
            ),

          // Here I Chaged the overline to my Custom TextStyle.
            textTheme: TextTheme(overline: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
            dialogBackgroundColor: mainColor,
          ),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
   
}
```

[image: Here is the Output of what I get]

Answer (score 0):

For change colors, font and etc. You must wrap element into Theme:

```
Widget returnRangePicker(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          accentColor: Colors.green,
          primaryColor: Colors.blue,
          buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
              highlightColor: Colors.green,
              buttonColor: Colors.green,
              colorScheme: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(
                  secondary: epapGreen,
                  background: Colors.white,
                  primary: Colors.green,
                  primaryVariant: Colors.green,
                  brightness: Brightness.dark,
                  onBackground: Colors.green),
              textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.accent)),
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) => FlatButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final List<DateTime> picked = await DateRangePicker.showDatePicker(
                context: context,
                initialFirstDate: DateTime.now(),
                initialLastDate:
                    DateTime.now()).add(Duration(days: 7),
                firstDate: DateTime(2015),
                lastDate: DateTime(2020));
            if (picked != null && picked.length == 2) {
              print(picked);
            }
          },
          child: Text(
            "Choose range",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

For more info you can check out the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization). or check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59104256/how-can-i-change-style-of-date-range-picker)